# Unexpected alert ends completely protractor test session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, protractor

I am using protractor as a test runner for our end-to-end testing of AngularJS app. Some code uses alert to report an error to the user. Yes, I know that is not the optimal approach to exception handling but this is the way the code was written (and it will be changed later).

However when an alert is shown (and not expected) an `UnexpectedAlertOpenException` is thrown and the whole protractor session is ended, no other tests are executed and the browser window is not closed and I have to close it manually.

Is there a way how to catch this exception and handle it so the spec that was being executed will be marked as failed with unexpected alert open reason and protractor will continue and execute the other specs?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may refer to this issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/308

Comment: Yeah, I tried that - it works when you are really expecting an alert to be shown, otherwise it throws an exception when an alert is not shown. Let's say I can't predict the alert to be shown ...